# How to display Arabic language in LVGL?

Tags: lvgl

LVGL can not display Arabic chars.

I use font `weiruanyahei.ttf`, but it doesn't include Arabic chars when I convert it to C arrays with LVGL's font convert tools. I have set  `LV_USE_BIDI` to 1 and `LV_USE_ARABIC_PERSIAN_CHARS` to 1 in `lv_conf.h`, but it doesn't work. So which font includes Arabic chars or there are other methods to display Arabic language?